# SSIS send output to multiple databases based on field content

Tags: ssis

I have a staging database where i load information related to all countries. From staging, depending up on a field (country_code) in all tables, i have to load full data into that database.
Eg: in staging, I have a field country_code in table country.  Depending on country_code, i have to load all tables in country_code to that database. If country_code is USA, i have to load
all tables to USA_database, if country_code is AUS then load all tables to AUS_database etc.,

PS: In staging database, all tables has a field 'country_code' so that it will be easy for mapping purpose.
PS2: All country databases has exact file structures.

What is the best way to load tables in different country databases from staging using SSIS?  Will conditional split work in this scenario? If yes, how can i connect to different databases 
based on condition?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, is this actually possible or do i have to create transformations for each server?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Will you always populate the same set of country databases? If you know you will always have to process USA, AUS, JPN, CAN, and CHN, for example, you can create separate data flows for each and then in your source task, you can filter your tables based on the country_code of that country.